# JetBrains Language Support Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin, bnf, jflex

I am trying to implement language support plugin for a basic language. I am following jetbrains's [tutorial](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/custom-language-support-tutorial.html) for simple language support (.properties file support basically) and on the side I have [rust plugin](https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust) for reference. However the complexity gap between them is huge so some questions are hard to find answers to from both sources.

Here is my question: What is the best way to allow spaces between tokens which DO NOT require spaces, however force spacing between tokens which do?

i.e. `class Foo{` <- here first space is mandatory, but the second one (before '{' symbol) can be ommited.

Comment: If you don't get the answer here, the best place to ask would be https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development.

Comment: thank you! should've considered there would be some jetbrains platform to discuss this as well :D

Answer (score 0):

That is a task for the Parser, not the Lexer. In fact the Lexer *lexes* the whitespaces but does not pass them to the Parser. To enforce or not enforce the whitespaces in your example you need to implement a `.bnf` file with the Grammar-Kit extension https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit.

Answer (score 0):

In general, parser doesn't handle whitespaces. In `com.intellij.lang.ParserDefinition`, you can find:

```
@NotNull
default TokenSet getWhitespaceTokens() {
    return TokenSet.WHITE_SPACE;
}
```

> Returns the set of token types which are treated as whitespace by the PSI builder. Tokens of those types are automatically skipped by `PsiBuilder`.

Your Lexer finds all white characters and marks them as `TokenType.WHITE_SPACE`. If there is no whitespace character in your example, it will simply treat the whole `classFoo` as a single unknown token.

In your implementation of `com.intellij.lang.ParserDefinition`, you can override method:

```
default @NotNull SpaceRequirements spaceExistenceTypeBetweenTokens(ASTNode left, ASTNode right)
```

to return `MAY`, `MUST`, `MUST_NOT` or `MUST_LINE_BREAK` depending on the type of nodes.

You can also specify more advanced spacing for auto-formatting in your `FormattingModelBuilder` described in the tutorial here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/formatter.html